# How to embed html in Google Forms question's description

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I am trying to adapt [Zack Akil's script](https://towardsdatascience.com/friendlier-data-labelling-using-generated-google-forms-d25e3e9f6aa6) to generate a Google Form from a Google Sheet using App Script, but one thing that I am struggling with is to make the sheet's input parsed as HTML. I generate a form based on my sheet, all the text on cells is placed in Forms as plain text, the HTML is not parsed (see figure below).

[image]

I pasted the script from Zack and I kindly ask you to point out where should I modify in order to have this parsed on the form.

```
function getSpreadsheetData(sheetName) {
  // Return an list of objects (one for each row) containing the sheets data. 
  
  var arrayOfArrays = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName || 'Sheet1').getDataRange().getValues();
  var headers = arrayOfArrays.shift();
  return arrayOfArrays.map(function (row) {
    return row.reduce(function (memo, value, index) {
      if (value) {
        memo[headers[index]] = value;
      }
      return memo;
    }, {});
  });
}

function create_ranges_for_data(form, data, data_section_name){
  
   // loop throughh each row
   data.forEach(function (row) {
      // create a new question page
      form.addPageBreakItem()
      // add page title
      form.addSectionHeaderItem()
          .setTitle(data_section_name);
      // create number range input with the title being the document to be labeled
      form.addScaleItem()
          .setTitle(row[data_section_name])
          .setBounds(1, 10)
          .setRequired(true);
  });
}

function make_form_using_column(column_name) {
  // create a new Google Form document
  
  var form = FormApp.create('Data labelling - ' + column_name)
  desc = "Thank you for taking the time to label this data!";
  
  form.setDescription(desc);
  form.setProgressBar(true);
  form.setShowLinkToRespondAgain(false)
 
  var data = getSpreadsheetData();
  
  create_ranges_for_data(form, data, column_name);
}

function gen_form(){
    var COLUMN_TO_USE = 'Input text'
    make_form_using_column(COLUMN_TO_USE);
}
```

Comment: Google Forms doesn't support HTML code or text formatting. There is only one option available to modify its appearance and it's called [`Customize Theme`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/145737?hl=en). However, there are many workarounds that can fit your situation. Depending on your needs, you can download the html of the form and modify it, you can install an add-on or you can simply paste [**bold** text](https://boldtext.io/). I would like to help you if you give me more context about your case. It's important to store the answers in a Form or a Spreadsheet would be okay?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use HTML text formatting. most sites block it because it poses a security risk. You might need to install an add-on or, like fullfine said, [use bold text](https://boldtext.io).